# ASUS Z87m/G30AB motherboard won't recognize WD Red 8TB HDD

Tags: hard-drive, motherboard, sata

I recently bought an 8TB WB MyBook and shucked the case to use the WD Red drive inside a PC. I test the drive in the enclosure befre shucking. I can't get 1 of my systems to recognize this drive.

I tried hooking it up to my motherboard, ASUS Z87M/G30AB, won't recognize the drive. First thing I did was re-test the drive in my other system. I was able to drop the drive into the hot-swap bay and it popped right up on the other system. I tried switching out the cables in the original system with ones that I know work. Then tried changing SATA ports with various cables. I also tried using a 4-port PCI-e expander. I moved on to updating the bios of the motherboard. Still no luck. I'm able to hook-up other drives up to both the cables and SATA ports and they work. The other drives I tested we 2x 3tb and 1x 2tb internal SATA.

From what I understand... as long as the mobo supports UEFI, it should be able to recognize the drive.

This system runs Ubuntu 18.10 and has an Intel 17-4770k CPU in the stated motherboard.

Why won't the motherboard recognize the HDD?

Answer (score -1):

I could be wrong but some motherboards have hard drive storage limitations.  Check your motherboard manual if you have one. Also look online for the manufacture of the motherboard for more info.  They may have the answer.

Comment: I tried but it looks like this mobo only came in the prefab PC and I can't find specific specs on it. I've got this same question into Asus but I'm trying to get feedback from other sources too. Thanks!

Comment: The author's motherboard does not have HDD size limitations and will support any SATA HDD.  However, the author isn't using a typical drive, their problem likely stems from it coming out of an external drive.

Comment: This is a common practice with these drives. They are white-labeled WD Reds. The fact that it works on another system also indicates that is most likely not the issue.